# Помогите поставить знаки препинания!

Tags: пунктуация

На некоторых островах Индонезии например хижины ставят у самого океана на высоких сваях.

Answer (score 1):

**Например** -- вводное слово. В данном предложении оно обособляется запятыми:
***На некоторых островах Индонезии, например, хижины ставят у самого океана на высоких сваях.***

**Правило:** http://ls-gramota.livejournal.com/3921.html